# Запуск от имени администратора

Tags: c#

Написал программу, которая запускается от имени администратора
Можно как-то сделать, чтобы не появлялось окно подтверждения?

Comment: Не думаю. В целях безопасности. Иначе какой смысл, если любой бы мог писать программы в обход UAC

Comment: А можно тогда как-то создавать файлы на системном диске без прав администратора?

Comment: да нет, по тем же причинам.

Comment: @andrew, отключения `UAC`, смотрите в сторону реестра Windows.

Comment: Сделать программу в виде службы, всегда будет от имени "Система" запускаться, иметь права больше чем у "администратора".

Comment: @andrew можно, раздать права пользователям создавать файлы на системном диске.

Comment: @pincher1519, но не в корне...

Answer (score 1):

Для этого создаётся служба, запускающаяся с правами администратора. Соответственно при установке появляется UAC-запрос, регистрируется служба и дальше она используется для запуска от админа без UAC-запроса.

Answer (score -1):

Пример как отключить `UAC` в реестре Windows

```
RegistryKey uac = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System",true);
if (uac == null)
{
 uac = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System");
}
uac.SetValue("EnableLUA", 1); // 1 on 0 off
uac.Close();
```

Так же посмотрите рекомендации [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191129/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-programatically) и [Тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/185264).

Comment: Бррррррр.. Руки за такое пообрывать...

Comment: @Qwertiy, Ну дык это пример)

Comment: Ага, помню я пример, как какая-то прога при установке спросила, хочу ли я, чтоб она запускалась без UAC-запроса. А потом оказалось, что она просто отключила UAC, когда я нажал Да.

Comment: Ну ничего же страшного не случилось?!) некоторым он вообще не нужен.

Comment: То, что _кому-то_ не нужна одна из ключевых фич безопасности, не означает, что это хороший совет. Кто-то может и под линуксом сидеть из-под рута, но это путь к превращению машины в рассадник вирусов. А уж если программа отключает UAC на компьютере клиента, это просто вредительство.